# How to use JPA outside of a web project?

Tags: java, netbeans, jpa, eclipselink

I've used eclipselink in a web project in NetBeans. It works nice and easy. How can I do the same in a project unrelated to the web (console application)?

In my web application I have:

```
@PersistenceUnit
EntityManagerFactory enf;
```

Which instantiates enf. This does not work in a console application.

Comment: the same way. What doesn't work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case of an Web or an application container, the container injects the `EntityManagerFactory` when the `@PersistenceUnit` annotation is called. This will not hold good for a console application.

The possible ways for achieving this are

1. To include Spring (which does the same job as your web container). Please refer to the tutorial *[Getting Started With JPA in Spring 2.0](http://blog.interface21.com/main/2006/05/30/getting-started-with-jpa-in-spring-20)*

Or

2. To write the initiation code yourself as follows.

   ```
   EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("PersistenceUnitName");
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I just need to call

```
enf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("JavaApplication39PU");
```

Where JavaApplication39PU is the name found in META-INF/persistence.xml

Answer (score 1):

When running within an EJB3 container (or Spring) you get the benefits of dynamic weaving with EclipseLink. If you are running in a JavaSE scenario I would recommend using the -javaagent to enable dynamic weaving so your application behaves the same.

Docs: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Using_EclipseLink_JPA_Extensions_%28ELUG%29#How_to_Configure_Dynamic_Weaving_for_JPA_Entities_Using_the_EclipseLink_Agent

Doug